# JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode - must begin with an object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm getting a JsonSerializationException calling DeserializeXmlNode() on JSON data that starts with [[ (i.e. it's an array of arrays).

What is the best

1. way to turn this into XML?
2. Are there any other JSON schemas that can't be turned into XML?

**Update:** How the XML should appear is an interesting question. Having an array of arrays means there is no root node (that's an easy one - insert ) but also the set of children nodes have no name. I'm not sure what makes sense here. And this may be a deal killer for using XPath on JSON. So on this part too, any suggestions?

**Update 2** - the JSON data:

```
[["P0010001","NAME","state"],
["4779736","Alabama","01"],
["710231","Alaska","02"],
["6392017","Arizona","04"],
["2915918","Arkansas","05"],
["37253956","California","06"],
["5029196","Colorado","08"],
["3574097","Connecticut","09"],
["897934","Delaware","10"],
["601723","District of Columbia","11"],
["18801310","Florida","12"],
["9687653","Georgia","13"],
["1360301","Hawaii","15"],
["1567582","Idaho","16"],
["12830632","Illinois","17"],
["6483802","Indiana","18"],
["3046355","Iowa","19"],
["2853118","Kansas","20"],
["4339367","Kentucky","21"],
["4533372","Louisiana","22"],
["1328361","Maine","23"],
["5773552","Maryland","24"],
["6547629","Massachusetts","25"],
["9883640","Michigan","26"],
["5303925","Minnesota","27"],
["2967297","Mississippi","28"],
["5988927","Missouri","29"],
["989415","Montana","30"],
["1826341","Nebraska","31"],
["2700551","Nevada","32"],
["1316470","New Hampshire","33"],
["8791894","New Jersey","34"],
["2059179","New Mexico","35"],
["19378102","New York","36"],
["9535483","North Carolina","37"],
["672591","North Dakota","38"],
["11536504","Ohio","39"],
["3751351","Oklahoma","40"],
["3831074","Oregon","41"],
["12702379","Pennsylvania","42"],
["1052567","Rhode Island","44"],
["4625364","South Carolina","45"],
["814180","South Dakota","46"],
["6346105","Tennessee","47"],
["25145561","Texas","48"],
["2763885","Utah","49"],
["625741","Vermont","50"],
["8001024","Virginia","51"],
["6724540","Washington","53"],
["1852994","West Virginia","54"],
["5686986","Wisconsin","55"],
["563626","Wyoming","56"],
["3725789","Puerto Rico","72"]]
```

Comment: What would you expect the resulting XML to look like?

Comment: Very good question - I answered with an update above.

Comment: @L.B - I want to use XPath. There is no clear standard for running a query on JSON and XPath maps well, except for this issue. If there was a clear query language for JSON, I would happily use that.

Comment: Can you show some sample json?

Comment: Yes, the link thedataweb.rm.census.gov/data/2010/sf1?key=d30412623269142547bfbe8210b8dd01af55c9ce&get=P0010001,NAME&for=state:* shows this kind of JSON (no http because S/O gets the link wrong)

Comment: David, I get `Invalid Key` error. You can post the json here.

Comment: i am try to convert this json.but i got the begin with object exeption     `[ "cochin", [   { "id" : "1273874", "name" : "Cochin", "fullName" : "Cochin, India" }  , { "id" : "6301122", "name" : "Cochin / Willingdon", "fullName" : "Cochin / Willingdon, India" }  ] ]   `

Answer (score 3):

I had an array of objects, shaped like:

```
[{foo:bar}, {foo:bar2}]
```

...What I did to work around this problem is to wrap the text first like so:

```
public XmlDocument JsonArrayToXml(string json)
{
    var wrappedDocument = string.Format("{{ item: {0} }}", json);
    var xDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(wrappedDocument, "collection");
    return xDocument;
}
```

This does not throw an error.  The shape of the XML resembles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<collection>
    <item>
        <foo>bar</foo>
    </item>
    <item>
        <foo>bar2</foo>
    </item>
</collection>
```